# continually running php artisan serve for a long period of time

Tags: php, linux, laravel, laravel-artisan

I'm running:

```
php artisan serve
```

And its working fine but shuts off after awhile. What's the way to always keep it on even if I close out of putty, etc..

Comment: Is it crashed? do you have any log?

Comment: Well I'm developing on a dev server and it will randomly shut off every now and then so I have to go back to putty and put in php artisan serve. Should it stay on forever if it were stable (not in dev)?

Comment: You should not use `serve` for production, but yes it should stay on forever. please check your storage/logs/laravel.log and see if anything unusual happens.

Comment: What would you use for production then?

Comment: You have to install a webserver like apache, nginx or anything you prefer. The serve option uses php `Built-in web server` which `runs a only one single-threaded process` [link](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php)

Comment: nginx is already install on the server...

Comment: Well that was just a hint :). Please mention your PHP version too

Comment: By the way nginx resolves fine so I know it's installed and works. PHP 7, PHP 7.0.15 to be exact.